# Add onclick to all anchors on page except for ones with a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sure this should be relatively easy to do with Jquery, but my attempts have not worked so far (I'm a little new at Jquery).

Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks!

Comment: What attempts have you made so far?

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the -1. Is it standard on Stackoverflow to be guilty until proven innocent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method

```
$('a').not('.someClass').click(function() { 
    //your code here...
});
```

**Note**: You can also use the [not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to filter directly, this is better for performance.

```
$('a:not(.someClass)').click(function() { 
    //your code here...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the jQuery [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector:

```
$("a:not(.some-class)").on("click", function(){
});
```

or the [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) function

```
$("a").not(".some-class").on("click", function(){
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

  $('a').not('.yourClassToIgnore').click(function() { 
    //do somethng    
  });

});
```

Jsfiddle sample : http://jsfiddle.net/S5XLv/2/

Comment: Thanks Shyju. antyrat beat you by a minute :-)